# I am getting output for the below code as 3, but I think it should be 6. Can anyone explain the below code?

Tags: java, recursion

Not able to understand what is happening here. The print statement is printing the output as 6, but the func function is return output as 3.

```
public class Main
{
   static int func(int[] arr,int n,int sum){
     if (n==0) return sum;
     sum+=arr[n];
     System.out.println("Inside functions "+sum);
     func(arr,n-1,sum);
     return sum;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[] arr={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
     int ans=func(arr,3,0);
     System.out.println(ans);
   }
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in returning the *sum* before saving the result from previous executions. So the sum in the first call of the function was never changed.

```
public class Main {
            static int sumArray(int[] arr, int i, int sum) {
                if (i == 0)
                    return sum;
                sum += arr[i];
                System.out.println("Inside function " + sum);
                sum = sumArray(arr, --i, sum); // saving result of the recursive function bevore returning
                return sum;
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) {
                int[] arr = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
                int ans = sumArray(arr, 3, 0);
                System.out.println(ans);
            }
        }
```

I renamed some of the namings for readability.